# DataTables, database serverside processing and "DataTables warning (table id = 'example')"

Tags: php, json, datatables, datatables-1.10

There are many peoples experiencing the following error with DataTables and server side processing with Ajax, but I've tried many of them and read all, without any success.

> DataTables warning (table id = 'example') - Invalid JSON response

I've also checked dev answers and they say that every time you that error is because you have or a json formatting problem, or a database connection problem or a column selection problem.
Well it seems to me I have none of them.

My code (got from this example: [here](https://legacy.datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html)) is (try.php):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />

<!-- DataTables CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"   href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8"  src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>

<title>test</title>
</head>

<body>
<table id="example">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>country Name</th>
            <th>country Currency</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
 </table>
 <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.4/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $('#example').dataTable( {
      "bProcessing": true,
      "bServerSide": true,
      "sAjaxSource": "server_processing2.php"
   } );
 } );

 </script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

And here is server_processing2.php:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
 <title>Processing</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <?php
 /*
 * Script:    DataTables server-side script for PHP and MySQL
 * Copyright: 2010 - Allan Jardine
 * License:   GPL v2 or BSD (3-point)
 */

 /* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * 
 * Easy set variables
 */

 /* Array of database columns which should be read and sent back to DataTables. Use a space where
 * you want to insert a non-database field (for example a counter or static image)
 */
 $aColumns = array('ID', 'country_Name', 'country_Currency' );

 /* Indexed column (used for fast and accurate table cardinality) */
 $sIndexColumn = "ID";

 /* DB table to use */
 $sTable = "CountryInfos";

 /* Database connection information */
 $gaSql['user']       = "...";
 $gaSql['password']   = "...";
 $gaSql['db']         = "...";
 $gaSql['server']     = "...";

 /* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * 
 * If you just want to use the basic configuration for DataTables with PHP server-side, there is
 * no need to edit below this line
 */

 /* 
 * MySQL connection
 */
 $gaSql['link'] =  mysql_pconnect( $gaSql['server'], $gaSql['user'], $gaSql['password']  ) or
    die( 'Could not open connection to server' );

 mysql_select_db( $gaSql['db'], $gaSql['link'] ) or 
    die( 'Could not select database '. $gaSql['db'] );


 /* 
 * Paging
 */
 $sLimit = "";
 if ( isset( $_GET['iDisplayStart'] ) && $_GET['iDisplayLength'] != '-1' )
 {
    $sLimit = "LIMIT ".mysql_real_escape_string( $_GET['iDisplayStart'] ).", ".
        mysql_real_escape_string( $_GET['iDisplayLength'] );
 }


 /*
 * Ordering
 */
 if ( isset( $_GET['iSortCol_0'] ) )
 {
    $sOrder = "ORDER BY  ";
    for ( $i=0 ; $i<intval( $_GET['iSortingCols'] ) ; $i++ )
    {
        if ( $_GET[ 'bSortable_'.intval($_GET['iSortCol_'.$i]) ] == "true" )
        {
            $sOrder .= $aColumns[ intval( $_GET['iSortCol_'.$i] ) ]."
                ".mysql_real_escape_string( $_GET['sSortDir_'.$i] ) .", ";
        }
    }

    $sOrder = substr_replace( $sOrder, "", -2 );
    if ( $sOrder == "ORDER BY" )
    {
        $sOrder = "";
    }
 }


 /* 
 * Filtering
 * NOTE this does not match the built-in DataTables filtering which does it
 * word by word on any field. It's possible to do here, but concerned about efficiency
 * on very large tables, and MySQL's regex functionality is very limited
 */
 $sWhere = "";
 if ( $_GET['sSearch'] != "" )
 {
    $sWhere = "WHERE (";
    for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
    {
        $sWhere .= $aColumns[$i]." LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string( $_GET['sSearch'] )."%' OR ";
    }
    $sWhere = substr_replace( $sWhere, "", -3 );
    $sWhere .= ')';
 }

 /* Individual column filtering */
 for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
 {
    if ( $_GET['bSearchable_'.$i] == "true" && $_GET['sSearch_'.$i] != '' )
    {
        if ( $sWhere == "" )
        {
            $sWhere = "WHERE ";
        }
        else
        {
            $sWhere .= " AND ";
        }
        $sWhere .= $aColumns[$i]." LIKE '%".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['sSearch_'.$i])."%' ";
    }
}


 /*
 * SQL queries
 * Get data to display
 */
 $sQuery = "
    SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS ".str_replace(" , ", " ", implode(", ", $aColumns))."
    FROM   $sTable
    $sWhere
    $sOrder
    $sLimit
 ";
 $rResult = mysql_query( $sQuery, $gaSql['link'] ) or die(mysql_error());

 /* Data set length after filtering */
 $sQuery = "
    SELECT FOUND_ROWS()
 ";
 $rResultFilterTotal = mysql_query( $sQuery, $gaSql['link'] ) or die(mysql_error());
 $aResultFilterTotal = mysql_fetch_array($rResultFilterTotal);
 $iFilteredTotal = $aResultFilterTotal[0];

 /* Total data set length */
 $sQuery = "
    SELECT COUNT(".$sIndexColumn.")
    FROM   $sTable
 ";
 $rResultTotal = mysql_query( $sQuery, $gaSql['link'] ) or die(mysql_error());
 $aResultTotal = mysql_fetch_array($rResultTotal);
 $iTotal = $aResultTotal[0];


 /*
 * Output
 */
 $output = array(
    "sEcho" => intval($_GET['sEcho']),
    "iTotalRecords" => $iTotal,
    "iTotalDisplayRecords" => $iFilteredTotal,
    "aaData" => array()
 );

 while ( $aRow = mysql_fetch_array( $rResult ) )
 {
    $row = array();
    for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
    {
        if ( $aColumns[$i] == "version" )
        {
            /* Special output formatting for 'version' column */
            $row[] = ($aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ]=="0") ? '-' : $aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ];
        }
        else if ( $aColumns[$i] != ' ' )
        {
            /* General output */
            $row[] = $aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ];
        }
    }
    $output['aaData'][] = $row;
 }
 echo json_encode( $output );
 ?>

 </body>
 </html>
```

Any try I've done, returned me that error but here is ARRAY I receive from server_processing2.php:

```
 {"sEcho":0,
  "iTotalRecords":"287",
  "iTotalDisplayRecords":"287",
  "aaData":[
     ["10768","Western Sahara","EH"],["10767","Vietnam","VND"],
     ["10765","Uzbekistan","UZS"],["10766","Venezuela","VEF"],       
     ["10764","USA","USD"],["10763","Uruguay","UYU"],["10762","United Kingdom","GBP"],
     ["10761","United Arab Emirates","AED"],["10760","Ukraine","UAH"],  
     ["10759","Uganda","UGX"],["10758","Turkmenistan","TMT"],.........   
     ["10546","Argentina","ARS"],["10545","Albania","ALL"],   
     ["10544","Afghanistan","AFN"]
   ]
 }
```

So I can assume that:

- my database works correctly (data is correct);
- JSON is well formatted (tested by JSON validator);
- data arrived to try.php (trunked after some results, but I guess is because DataTable works with 10 results a time...

So why it doesn't work?

***UPDATE***

It works. There were (I guess) two problems:

1. I needed to update DataTables to last versions
2. As suggested I needed to eliminate html part from server side file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have HTML in your `server_processing2.php`. Remove everything except PHP code between `<?php` and `?>` tags so it returns JSON only.

Comment: amazing, I've update DT to last version and eliminated "html" part of code in "server_processing2.php" file and it worked.
Anyone can explain me why?

Thx anyway for your big help!!!

Comment: @AlbertoSupertrampGiorgis, the error occurred because your PHP script returned mixed content (HTML with JSON) which client-side script doesn't expect.